# How long a spiral copper tube would need to be in a monotube boiler in order to achieve 0.02 kg of steam per second?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, steam, steamengine

So, I'm trying to calculate how much fuel/energy I would need to input in a homemade monotube steam turbine engine in order to achieve 15hp (11kw), the idea is that the engine will run at this specific power, not that I will take 11kw out of a generator.

[image: Illustration of the homemade monotube steam turbine engine]

(I didn't add a water pump because it is out of space on the image, but just pretend that in the bottom check valve there is a water pump)

I didn't knew where to start, so I looked on a [website about micro jet turbines](https://jakadofsky.com/index1.php?bereichID=7&lang=en) and found that the 10kw (13-14hp) turboshaft has a length of 30cm and a diameter of 14cm and can achieve 100,000 RPM. Even though this doesn't necessarily means that the turbine is 14cm in diameter, I took that value to base myself.

With that in mind, I used an [online steam generator calculator](https://www.codecalculation.com/htm/calculate/mechanical/engines/steam-turbine-performance/) that I found on the internet, and writing down that I would achieve **10 bar** of pressure on the input, **450-500 ºC** of temperature and **11kw** of output, the calculator gave the conclusion that I would need **0.02797 kg** of mass flow per second.

I assumed that this mass flow means flow of steam, I also assumed that I would need to convert 0.2 liters of water into steam per second, which would give 12 liters per minute. However, I asked in other websites, and some people gave me the answer that it should be 0.02 liters of water per second, which would be just around 1.2 liters per minute.

---

**The question:**

Taking into consideration that the heat source is 450 ºC, the copper tube has 6.35 mm of outer diameter with 0.79 mm of wall thickness, and the heat transfer of the copper tubing, what should be the length of the copper tube in order to convert 0.2 liters of water per second into 0.02kg of steam?

Comment: So how much heat are you transferring in terms of watts? Just stating a temperature is not sufficient.

Comment: @SolarMike Well, I don't know, I thought that the length of the copper would be inherently tied to the amout of heat transferred.

Comment: The short answer is that you haven't provided the information needed to answer your question, because heat transfer rate will be almost totally determined by the conditions on the outside of the tube - which you've told us nothing about.  But your question raises many other questions in my mind.  Have you considered whether copper is a good material for building a boiler which will produce superheated steam at 450 °C?  Is a single coiled tube a good design for a boiler producing superheated steam?  Are you aware of all the safety requirements for a boiler operating at those conditions?

Comment: @Mark Nope, I didn't consider the safety requirements, in fact, I don't know anything about the subject. But I guess I can't just go around asking people to design a 15cv steam engine for free, so I'm learning along the way.

Comment: Any idea of how copper will behave at the temperatures you suggest? You might enjoy this: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/j.2050-0416.1926.tb04987.x

Comment: @SolarMike I do not, I expected that the constant flow of water would absorb the heat from the copper tubing. Also, I didn't read the text yet, what is it about?

Comment: So anything useful that I suggest you won't read... Ah well won't mention tables about the properties of water then, AKA steam tables - well known by engineers.

Comment: @SolarMike ... I was occupied at the moment you suggested me to read the text, in fact, I'm still doing some stuff by now. Don't be so dramatic >.>

Comment: @SolarMike Steam tables are well known by engineers... And I'm not an engineer, so even if you mentioned/showed me those, I don't think I would even understand. I don't have the same knowledge, expertise and concentration as you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I'm not going to answer your question, because no wall thickness or length of tube will meet your needs.

Coiled copper is for cooling something, not for making steam.  You can cool hot water by putting cold water through a submerged coil in that hot water.  You could also make cold water in the tubing by running it through ice.

One can *theoretically* make steam like this, but this type of boiler has been relegated to the dust bins of engineering.

Go look at any old steam engine or boiler design.  Exactly none of them except a few steam powered cars used (or now uses) a monotube boiler.  This is because it's just too hard to make it work.  Your design would turn water in the lower part of the loop to steam, which unless you had a very low steaming rate would eject all the water from the top of the loop into your turbine resulting in an empty loop until all the pressure was gone and the water column of the water tank had enough pressure to let some water back in. Evidence suggests that controlling the steaming rate for these is very difficult.  This will not be superheated steam (which you should understand if you are trying to build anything other than a burner that runs on Esbit fuel).

Your coil, since it is fed solely by gravity, would constantly go from hot to cold, and no material will stand up to that.  The output would also go from high flow to zero flow, since you have no method to put water into the system other than gravity.

What you need in a boiler:

- A pressure-tested and approved boiler vessel, usually some type of cylinder shape.  10 bar pressure will kill you in a heartbeat doing this wrong.
- A constant level of water in the boiler.  This is done via feedwater pumps or steam injectors.  Look up steam locomotive explosions to understand the problems of not properly maintaining this water level.
- If you use tubes, they need to be attached to the boiler vessel in the right way.  Boilermaker is the term for people who know how to do this.  The tubes also need to work for the temperatures and pressures of the design; this one probably calls for steel, but I've never tried to design a boiler; certainly the history of such designs is littered with disasters.
- head space above the water level to prevent water droplet carryover.  Steam turbines do not like water drops.
- Superheater tubes are not for use by the unknowledgeable.  Stick with saturated steam for your first attempt.  Understand the steam tables before you try this.
- A pressure relief valve to keep from blowing up the boiler if it heats up too much
- Control of the heating to keep the pressure in the desired range.  On a steam locomotive this was the fireman's rate of shoveling coal.  Modern boilers use pressure control via the fuel feed.
- A good steam system will have a condenser that draws a vacuum on the turbine outlet to increase its efficiency.  It isn't strictly necessary, but your system doesn't have a way to get rid of waste heat.  Eventually the water tank will be filled with water near the boiling point, which will just make it flash to steam that much quicker entering your furnace.

I recommend starting with hobby steam engines and boilers and build from there.  I really like [Keith Appleton](https://www.youtube.com/@keithappleton) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

ASME (USA Clever Engineers) state that copper shall not be used above 100psi... because it loses strength too much above 200deg.C.
So do not go to 450psi !!!